# How do I send a C# file in Visual Studio C# 2008 express edition along with the database in one zip file?

Tags: c#

I have used Ms-Access(2000-2003) file format and Visual Studio C# Express 2008 Edition to create a WinForms application. I need to satisfy the following condition:

> All code and referenced assemblies must be submitted in one zip file.  We need to be able to unzip and run the VS solution without changing settings, adding references or creating any databases.

Comment: Are you asking how you can make your program create the database file if it doesn't exist?

Comment: which database are you connecting to? Access or SQL Server?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to trigger DB installation without some kind of installer (like MSI). You should consider using [embedded database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database) like SQL Server Compact or SqLite (used by Firefox) etc.

Comment: @Lasse V Karlsen ok fine I will put it this way I have already created a windows forms application with connectivity to Ms-Access database and now if you want to run my code in your system how can I send you the program so that you can run the program in ur computer?

Comment: @user561730, build the project and send the person the executable and a copy of the database. If your windows form can create the database from scratch then you don't send the database.

Comment: Create a setup program? Or just ask the user to unzip everything and not double-click the program file *in* the zip file.

Comment: Edited the question to remove the irrelevant homework rules stuff, distilled it down to the problem at hand.

Comment: @Black Frog I dont think my windows form can create the database because i created the database and then made the connection between the Application and database

Comment: @user561730 you will have to include the database in your zip file. Simple.

Comment: @black frog ok fine but in the OleDBConnection the Data Source to the Database wouldn't that be a problem because I have the local path for the database?

Comment: @user561730: you're welcome sir, folks were answering the wrong questions. Wanted to nip that in the bud :)

Answer (score 1):

You want the `mdb` to go with your executable, so:

1. Place the Access `mdb` file into your solution by right clicking on the Project and using *Add Existing Item*.
2. Once you have added the `mdb` file to your project, find it in Solution Explorer and right click on it and goto *Properties*.
3. Once there change the *Build Action* to **Content**, and set *Copy to Output Directory* to **Copy If Newer**.
4. Change any references to the `mdb` file to be relative--i.e. `@"mydata.mdb"`--as it will be copied alongside your EXE at compile time.

Now the database will *follow* your executable at compile and run whether you're in Debug or Release. This doesn't fix the situation where the target machine doesn't support Access, but that is not a problem you can solve through your project file.

Comment: Thank you Sir I have done what you had advised but how do I confirm that its working?

Comment: Copy your Solution folder to some other place on disk. Delete the Debug and/or Release folders in this new location. Open up the Solution folder and goto Debug -> Start Debugging. If it works in this new, clean location you'll know it works.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a file based database such as [SQL CE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact). This will make bundling the database with your application very easy.

Comment: @user561730 - And what happens when you zip it up with the application and try running on another computer?

Comment: @Oded I am unable to try it because both my room-mates have Linux operating system. I dont know what to do ?

Comment: @user561730 - Linux has .NET support via [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page).

Comment: and windows have virtual machine support

Comment: @Oded: I doubt Mono has the MS Access support needed. It also doesn't have the best WinForms support either.

Comment: If you have built an application using .Net don't expect it to work on linux, .net framework is a microsoft product, and whilst they support Mono it isn't 100% right and has many missing features. If you need cross platform compatibility I recommend you use Java instead.

Comment: @JonWillis I accept but what I am asking is if I send the zip file how can the other person run the application without changing the data source in the OleDbConnection String.

Comment: @user561730, Depends on the string. If you are connecting to a local file it might be possible, i.e. "mydatabase.mbd" rather than "c:\data\mydatabase.mdb". Or have a dialog and them navigate to the files location. Also you need a assembly on linux that can read the mbd file.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your project has external dependencies to a database server. In that scenario it's not possible to package that dependency along with the application. You can resolve the issue by removing your dependency on an external database server, and use a file based database instead (such as SQl Server Compact or SqlLite). Your dependency is then a single file, which is simple to deploy with the rest of your project.

Comment: I believe he chose Access, which isn't exactly a database "server".